# Handling Slightly Unpredictable Situations

Tags: gm-techniques, new-gm, gm-preparation

So it was my first time DMing for experienced players and were playing through The Sunless Citadel. Most of what happened happened accordingly to the book expect dialogue, which I was expecting. What I wasn't expecting was the players lighting the entirety of the Twilight Grove on fire.

Not knowing how the handle the situation I was tempted to not let their inner pyro flourish, but decided against it and let them light the place ablaze. Was there anyway I could have handled that better as a DM?

Comment: Is your question specifically "How could I have handled this situation better?" or "How can I learn to better handle unpredictable situations"? I think you should either update the title or the question itself to make it more clear, so we know what you'd like to hear :)

Comment: This question needs some indication of what "better" means.  If the problem is that you're not sure, and specifying it would be basically answering your own question, try explaining what you thought was "bad" either about the situation or your handling of it.

Comment: A system tag would also help-- this seems like it could be 3e or 5e, at a glance.

Comment: @Novak I disagree. This isn't a system question.

Comment: It IS a system question if his question is about that specific situation. Or at least, system would be a factor. But it's not a system question if - as it reads to my eyes - he's asking for more general advice on handling such curve balls.

Comment: I agree with @Novak. Tagging it with the system used won't prevent good system-agnostic answers from coming in. But it might allow answerers to leverage tools a GM might have in one system but not the other.

Comment: Yes, please do specify what system and edition you're using. Different systems/editions have different expectations and handling in their philosophies for unpredictable situations, and different tools for handling and resolving them, and different expectations for what situations are supposed to be standard and unpredictable. All of that is relevant to answering this question, and withholding information about the system and edition is withholding information that could majorly influence the answers received. Gameplay questions are inherently system-specific because of these factors.

Answer (score 17):

### Every situation you face as a GM is unpredictable

The whole reason tabletop RPGs *have* a GM and computer RPGs and board games don’t, is because players can, will and should be encouraged to do wild, crazy and unexpected things: the GM is there to enable that.

Your initial instinct to shut them down was wrong but you showed GM greatness by suppressing that instinct and, in response to your players suggesting a plan which made your sphincter shrink in panic, you said yes. Well done.

The only advice I have is: do it again and again and keep on doing it.

All tabletop RPG games that have a GM (some don't) that I have ever encountered have some variation of a core mechanic that goes:

1. The GM describes the environment,
2. The PCs initiate a course of action,
3. The GM determines the outcome (with a greater or lesser involvement of mechanics depending on the system). When the players step outside the boundaries of the mechanics the GM has to wing it.

Comment: To add to that, if they do something wildly unexpected, it's OK to call time-out while you think about what happens next.

Comment: Exactly this, growing as a Game Master is often just getting better at dealing with unexpected situations. The fun thing about tabletop RPGs is that players can come up with any sort of wild things and the master's role is to keep things consistent and fun, with the help of game rules.

Comment: I would add one more to Dale M's answer: 4. Consequences. This is the next level. Showing them their world is real by having them answer for their actions.

Answer (score 9):

### **"Oh God, Why?"**

Seriously, though. Your players have done something you didn't expect. This also means you are probably underinformed as to what it is they're trying to accomplish.

It's important that you find out why, preferably by asking them directly. Because

> I'm setting the grove on fire because it should be purged from existence in cleansing flame

is different from

> I'm setting the grove on fire to create a distraction

is different from

> I'm setting the grove on fire to see if it's an illusion

and it may be possible that they were trying to accomplish something you had planned for, but just coming at it weird. If so, all well and good.

### **The Actual Curveball**

If not, okay, you need some time to think.

**Say "I need some time to think."** Seriously. Ask people to take a snack break or a bio break or something, so you can work through things. Set a timer for like ten minutes, at the outside, to give yourself a limit and tell the players you're going to get back in action and not just have a sulk.

Now think.

1. Who cares about the thing the PCs are going to break?
2. How are they going to find out?
3. How are they going to react?
4. Is there any way the PCs would know the approximate answers to 1-3?
5. No, there is. What is it?

Okay, so I'm being a little facetious there. If what the PCs are going to wreck is just some forgotten relic that has no real value to anybody, let them at it. Otherwise, make it clear that you'll respect their decision, but tell them what they're getting in to. If they keep going, now you've thought some about what's going to happen.

Comment: I haven't ever used the "I need some time to think" but that is great advice.